# Как передать указатель на первую форму второй?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

C++/CLI. По нажатию кнопки на второй форме нужно менять поле в первой

Request1Form.h

```
#include "MyForm.h"
namespace WinFormsCpp {
    public ref class Request1Form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: MyForm^ parentForm;
    public:
        Request1Form(MyForm^ parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            parentForm = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#include "Request1Form.h"
namespace WinFormsCpp {
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    // ...
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int column = comboBox4->SelectedIndex + 1;
        Request1Form^ newForm = gcnew Request1Form(this);
        newForm->changeProperties(column);
        newForm->Show();
    }
}
```

Ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое верное решение: не использовать C++/CLI для написания приложений. Dixi.

Comment: Не стоит ставить вопросу теги не относящихся к проблеме языков. Также не стоит приводит текст ошибок картинкой.